# How do I edit visibility of a frame using EventHandler's actionPerformed method?

Tags: java, arrays, jframe, actionlistener, java-io

This is a simple vending machine.
As shown below, I am trying to handle the event of a button click from a frame in the actionPerformed() method.

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

       if (e.getSource() == drink) {

         int i = 0;

         try {

           File fl = new File("Product List.txt");

           Scanner scn = new Scanner(fl);

           while (scn.hasNext()) {

             String productName = scn.next();

             double productPrice = scn.nextDouble();

             int productAmount = scn.nextInt();

             product[i] = new Products(productName, productPrice, productAmount);

             i = i + 1;

           }

           object.checkoutDrinks(product);

         } catch (IOException exc) {

           File fl = new File("Product List.txt");

         }

       }

       if (e.getSource() == snack) {

         int i = 0;

         try {

           File fl = new File("Product List.txt");

           Scanner scn = new Scanner(fl);

           while (scn.hasNext()) {

             String productName = scn.next();

             double productPrice = scn.nextDouble();

             int productAmount = scn.nextInt();

             product[i] = new Products(productName, productPrice, productAmount);

             i = i + 1;

           }

           object.checkoutSnacks(product);

         } catch (IOException exc) {

           File fl = new File("Product List.txt");

         }

       }
```

I am trying to read from an existing file and instantiate another class with those values.

The problem is when the click event is sent and passed to the method above, the next frame will not show. I thought that it could not be registering the event but it actually was.

Comment: I believe you should use `e.getSource().equals()` instead of `==`

Comment: Also, is your action listener added to anything? Is there any way to verify that the source you posted actually runs? What are `object` `drink` and `snack` ?

Comment: object is to allow me access to a method in a different class, drink and snack are button object names... actually in my blondness, i forgot to add the action listener... i have been freaking out for the past 12 hours over something so simple. thank you very much